# How to define a compute in a field in the GUI Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am creating a field in the GUI Odoo have a method with the 'compute'. But I can't get it.

I have a field created with the compute attribute in sale.order.line of sale.py module.

```
niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", compute="_niu_validation", readonly=True, store=True)

@api.depends('product_id.product_tmpl_id.type')
def _niu_validation(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not rec.niu:
                rec.niu = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
```

This works perfectly , but this same want to do in the GUI Odoo.

Below the image is displayed:http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/computefield.php

But it shows me the following error:

```
ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in u"for rec in self:\n        if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not rec.niu:\n \t    rec.niu = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')"
```

Maybe there is a syntax error, but I don't know how to define a method for a field in the GUI Odoo.

Any help , advice, suggestions are welcome. If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Did you try to avoid the for loop? Maybe try just remove it and use only if condition.

Comment: Now I get the following error:

 ValueError: "name 'rec' is not defined" while evaluating

Comment: When I said to avoid the loop, of course you needed to adapt the rest of the code!

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to assign the value with a dictionary-like assignment instead of the self. annotation, for example:

```
 self.x_hora_estimada_llegada = self.date_order
```

Will throw

> forbidden opcode(s) in u....

But instead you use the dictionary-like assignment and your field will be just fine!:

```
for record in self:
    record['x_hora_estimada_llegada'] = self.date_order
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not work with v9, so I think you just need to do a little of trial and error.

Try with this:

```
    if self.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not self.niu:
            self.niu = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
```

If it doesn't work, maybe try with:

```
    if self.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not self.niu:
            return self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
```

Comment: it cannot be the same: rec is no more in my code. Which value it doesn't accept?

Comment: The first code shows the following error:
ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in u"if self.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not self.niu:\n            self.niu = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')"

And the second code shows the following error:
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: This is not really helpful. What I would do, lacking documentation, is to put breakpoints and debug step-by-step the parser of the *Calcular* field to understand what you can put there, and what you can't

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

I've faced a similar issue, you can try with

> if self.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not self.niu:
>          self.['niu'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')